# What do I request from the LAN upgrade contractor to avoid simple oversights?

Tags: wifi, local-area-network, ethernet

The company for which I work have allowed me to hire a LAN wiring contractor to completely overhaul the building LAN. Currently there are old 10MBit Ethernet cables and switches running and I requested Gigabit LAN with a new power managing switch and wifi AP on each of the two floors. Currently there are about 10 computers on each floor. No server.

We are switching to a cloud-based financing system, hence needing a good internet connection. We are also planning deployment of Google Apps as well as upgrading to a 20MBit downstream internet connection (currently 5MBit). I see Google Apps have a technical best practise page; ideas?

Question is: Are there any services and/or tips/tricks I shall request from the contractor to make sure nothing commonly known is overseen? I don't want to miss out on simple great fixes! :-)

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? This question is all over the place. Is this a wiring contractor that will be pulling new cable in your walls? A network engineer that will be installing and configuring a new route-switch environment? A systems admin that will be configuring google apps for your company?

Comment: "Currently no employees use networking features nor network printers" - Hmmm... then you really don't need a network.

Comment: Sorry for the messy question. I am just trying to cover my bases not knowing enough of this myself. 
Yes, it is a wiring contractor who will pull new cables in the house as well as installing new switches and wifi APs. As I am not sure of the quality of my contractor, I was hoping to gain some insight in some best practises to avoid overseeing some typical network optimisations and/or tips/tricks commonly known.

Comment: Well we do need a network as we need to distribute the internet connection in the building. More network collaboration is to come as well as networked printers, faxes and copying machines.

Comment: [A link to the list of Canonical Questions](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1986/what-are-the-canonical-answers-weve-discovered-over-the-years) would probably be more helpful. Simply looking at what's written on the cables is all I would expect from a non-technical user. He's probably writing the network policy/specificion, and it's unlikely to be a thourough document as it's a fairly small business. PCI compliance is a good question, though I'd hope he'd have a "real" System Admin if that was the case. It's best to shy away from storing Credit Card numbers and related..

Comment: Thank you both. I am reading up on the canonical questions now. Good info there. I do not know of the local authorities' rules here in Malaysia, I assume the contractor does. I did not know I needed to plan cable certifications nor do I know what PCI even means :-) I appreciate all your help. Sorry for being fresh on all this stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few thoughts - no guarantees as I know extremely little about your office...

Wiring:

Gigabit Ethernet should be sufficient for the near future (next 5 to 10 years). It's hard to imagine this not being the case given the relatively slow progression of high speed Internet connections in most places. You'll be looking for Cat5e (not anything else).

<sub>Side note for those who think they know about Ethernet cabling categories: Cat3 will do 10Mbps. Cat5 = 100Mb. Cat5e = 1Gb. Cat6a = 10Gb. Cat7a = 40Gb (and 100Gb at short distance). There's no reason to use Cat4, Cat6, or Cat7 as cheaper cables are just as fast.</sub>

Make sure they use a patch panel. It's a little extra cost, but saves a world of headache in organization, reconfiguration, and basically any time there's a modicum of change.

Switching:

The core of the network is the switch, you'll want something managed, but seeing as you only have about two dozen endpoints you'll want to stick to the lower end of that spectrum. The quick and dirty requirement is that the switch has a "console" port (this will be a physical connection as pictured below). I highly recommend Cisco, ProCurve, Juniper, or Extreme (though others are acceptable compromises when budget demands).

[image: Cisco Console][image: HP Console][image: Juniper Console]

Having a managed switch enable a wide variety of possible upgrades, configurations, and utility in solving odd problems. I'd suggest something like the ProCurve 2510-48G; ProCurve gear comes with a transferable lifetime warranty and software upgrades, and it's generally easy to find on secondary source markets (eBay) at very cheap prices. (Full disclosure: I have no interest/affiliation with HP/ProCurve, just a fan of their products).

As for switch quantity and location; I your office seems small enough that you could get away with a single 48 Port switch (a typical office needs about twice as many Switch Ports as there are employees, for printers, servers, and other odd devices that get plugged in). each port on a Gigabit Ethernet switch is capable of 1Gbps in both directions. The switch itself has a backplane capacity, called the switching fabric. If all 48 Ports want to talk to someone else at their full 2Gbps then the switching fabric has to be able to get all those connections to their destinations. Within a modern switch this is no problem.

If instead you get two 24 Port switches, you still have 48 Ports total, but the two switches have to be connected to each other. If you use a single Port on each to connect them, then you have two halves of the network and a 2Gbps bottleneck in-between. There are switches with 10Gb (or rarely 40Gb) connections that can reduce the effects of the bottleneck; but they cost more, and the cable to connect them costs more.  You can also bond multiple cables between the two switches, if you used two cables you could get 4Gb total. Which also adds redundancy. Say you only use one cable, if it gets damaged (kicked, unplugged, "oops", etc) then half of your network becomes disconnected. If you're using two cables then both would need to be damaged. And you can generally add up to four if you want. Using two switches is simpler in some ways, especially for the installer. But it does have drawbacks, and the solutions to those are complicated.

Wireless:

You mentioned two APs already; which sounds roughly correct for a smaller office. If your environment is "clean" (no other wireless networks or sources of noise around), or if you're willing to accept "less than great performance" then consumer SOHO gear works. If you want reliable performance and problem mitigation then you should be looking at the same manufacturers listed above (there are other good names out there, prices will be similar). Make sure it's 802.11n, 5GHz, and at least 2SS (dual Spacial Stream; or more is better).

Router:

You don't mention what router you're using now. If it working well for you and can handle at least the 20Mb connection you're upgrading to, then it should be good enough at least for the time being.

If you're looking to change; same companies as listed above generally. But, it's really hard to argue against a Cisco ASA 5505, or similar Cisco router.

Labeling:
Make sure everything is reasonable labeled. The wall jacks should be labeled with the patch panel somehow (even if it's just a "map" that shows Patch Panel Port 1 goes to 'this desk'). Extremely complete documentation is going to drive up the price, and a small business isn't like to use it often... But minimal labeling or mapping shouldn't cost extra and allows troubleshooting to be significantly easier in the even of problems.

Google Apps:

The above is really all a network of your size is going to need for an optimal Google Apps experience; or any cloud based solution for that matter. The technical guidance Google provides applies almost exclusively to large networks with problems you'll not encounter in small networks.

Other thoughts:

If you want to upgrade to an IP based phone system in the near future (VoIP) be sure to mention that as it may affect the choice of equipment for some of the above. VoIP systems are a somewhat expensive investment however, it would certainly be a lot to do all at once.

Comment: I would argue for Cat6 cabling rather than Cat5e.

Comment: Your answer is simply AWESOME! Exactly the type of information I was looking for! Keep it coming! The current contractor did not talk about these options at all. I will take all your points and re-discuss with him directly. Many thanks. I will give you the answer credits soon, hoping some more good points will come in too!

Comment: @PaulGear what is your reasoning behind this? Interested to know as I also thought Cat6 was needed for gigabit...?

Comment: Quick thought: The contractor already has suggested the use of __two__ switches, one on each floor. What is the advantages of one switch vs. two?

Comment: @PaulGear You would argue incorrectly. Cat5e is required for Gigabit Ethernet. Cat6 still only does Gigabit Ethernet and costs more; so you would be arguing for him to pay more, and get the exact same thing?? You probable meant Cat6a, which is capable of 10 Gigabit Ethernet, but it's not what you said. Cat6a is very expensive (about 5x the cost of Cat5e), and it's very unlikely that any smaller office would use it in the next 5-10 years.

Comment: I know that Gigabit Ethernet only requires Cat5e, but building cabling tends to stay in place for decades, and over time technology often manages to make better use of it, so putting in the best you can afford at the time is a good investment.  There's a standard being developed at the moment to do 100 Mbps over 2 wires, so i wouldn't be surprised if they manage 10 or 40 Gbps over 8 wires of Cat6 quality one day...

Comment: @PaulGear I sincerely doubt any different standards than the ones already developed will ever be used. 10Base-T was developed about 23 years ago and hasn't changed. 100Base-TX 18 years ago, no changes. Someone might be messing about with updating the 14 year old 1000Base-T, but I can't possibly see a compelling, cost effective reason that 14 years of 'economies of scale' could be reversed. While it's technically possible to squeeze 10Gbps out of Cat6 cabling, there are realistic limitations. And "hopes and dreams" isn't a good reason to spend noticeably extra on cabling.

Comment: @ChrisS You seem to have conflated updates to existing standards with my suggestion about new standards over existing cabling.  Originally, Cat5 was 100 Mbps only, but now we run Gigabit over Cat5e, which is a tightening of the Cat5 specifications but didn't actually require new cable (in most cases). The same could happen again.

Comment: @PaulGear You're confusing cabling that **may** work with cabling that is **guaranteed** to work. Also, you should check your suggestion about new standards, as it's running 100Mb over a single pair. This sort of irreverence for details is the exact attitude that leads to wasteful spending and exaggerated capability claims. What you're suggesting is that someone spend *extra* money *hoping* that it *might* pay off at a *distant* future date, and using unrelated examples as some kind of misguided justification.

Comment: @PaulGear If you really thought they should spend extra money now, trying to future-proof their network cabling for an extended period you should have at least suggested Cat6a cabling, especially when it was pointed out that it is capable of 10GE now. Instead you've gone off on tangents about the possibilities of improved cabling utilization, despite no such event actually occurring in the history of Ethernet as any sort of widely accepted standard.

Comment: @ChrisS You've already pointed out the massive price difference between Cat5e and Cat6a. I would have thought that sufficient reason not to suggest it.

Comment: @HenrikSöderlund, you be the judge: price the difference between the various standards and decide for yourself whether you think getting higher-specced cable is a good investment.

Comment: Interesting discussion. Thanks for your insights. I will ask about the price difference and then decide like you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

I think Chris S's suggestions are all good ones, aside from my minor quibble about cabling standards.

I would add that you should insist on a map of the exact locations of all data points, and labeling which matches exactly on the patch panel and the wall socket.  Many cabling contractors i've encountered are less than enthusiastic about documentation.